# Setting custom plugin in sidebar open by default - Jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyterlab, the file browser plugin is open by default. How do you change this to have your custom plugin open by default on launch.

In the activation function of my custom plugin, i have the following snippet and I think the change needs to be in here-

```
// If the layout is a fresh session without saved data, open my custom plugin
  app.restored.then(layout => {
    if (layout.fresh) {
    console.log('This is a fresh launch, open custom plugin by default');
     //do something here
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that in your `active` function:

```
app.restored.then(() => {
  labShell.activateById(formationPanel.id);
});
```

Inspiration: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/filebrowser-extension/src/index.ts#L687